# Secured MD5/Encrypted form based login for JBoss portal

Tags: security, jboss, jboss-portal

I have currently created a form based login for JBoss portal server and my login page looks like (served on HTTPS only):

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
     Enter UserName: <input name="j_username" type="text" />

     Enter Password: <input name="j_password" type="password" />

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
     </form>
```

During security testing of application, it was recommended to not send the password in plain text and instead have some MD5 or other encryption, so that no one can extract the password on intercepting the request.

How can I implement this in JBoss portal form based login?

Comment: You are right not to send passwords in the clear.  Is the page served via `https`?  If not, then a MITM can insert a keylogger into the page so there's no point in encrypting it.  If `j_security_check` is never served except via HTTPS, then what do you hope to gain by using a scheme like MD5 that has been rainbow-tabled?

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Yes this page is served via https only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten some bad advice here.

Best standard practice is to send the password itself to the server, provided the link is SSL/TLS protected. Your application should receive that password, hash it (not using MD5 but a legitimate salted hash (or bcrypt, which is the best solution there)) and then compare it to the stored salted hash. Therefore, your application never stores user passwords, so if your password file/database got compromised, noone's password would be exposed and, if you use a strong salted hash/bcrypt algorithm noone should be able to brute force the hash to recover the actual password.

However, you need to do this on the SERVER side, within your application. Your application should take the password and do this hashing. If you hash the password on the client and send the actual salted hash to the application, you're opening yourself up to a different attack. If someone did steal your password file/database, they would know the hash of a user's password. If you have the client send the hash to the server, an attacker would then know exactly what hash to send and could access any user's account! Instead you want the client to send the password itself and have the server generate the hash based on it, so the attacker would not know what to send in an attempt to log in as a user (since you cannot take a salted hash and recover the password from it, assuming a strong salted hash implementation).

Comment: The problem here is that if a user is trying to intercept the request using a tool such as Webscarab, the interceptor will be able to see the password in clear text and use it later for doing any malicious activity on server. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: That's why "provided the link is SSL/TLS encrypted." If that's the case, it's encrypted end-to-end and any proxy server in the middle should be detectable as the certificate should not match.

Comment: My test server doesn't have valid certificate and I am able to intercept the request using Webscarab, can invalid test certificate (created by me) be the culprit?

Comment: You can intercept the request if you're running webscarab on your local machine (same as the client)...but I don't understand what threat you're trying to guard against here. Are you trying to prevent the user from intercepting their own request so they can read their own password (that they just submitted)? And yes, if you do proper certificate validation/checking and use CA-issued certificates on your server, you should be able to detect when you're connecting to a proxy server that is intercepting your SSL/TLS sessions as the SSL/TLS tunnel would terminate at the proxy.